How can I delete these floating entities in Minecraft that exploiters have spawned to lag the server?
Griefers have spawned these floating entities in my server (Ender Dragon and fire charges) that I cannot interact with. They are causing serious lag, due to the ender dragon having a huge name of random characters.
How can I delete these entities without having to resort to deleting the entire world?



This is a Minecraft Java Edition server running Paper/Spigot.
The dragon doesn't seem to really exist as a living entity and is immune to /butcher.

If I'm correct, ender dragons that were spawned with commands, custom spawn eggs (prior to 1.19.3/22w44a when the Ender Dragon spawn egg was added (untested)), or otherwise improperly spawned don't take damage due to the multi-part hitbox not being properly set up (which is why /butcher didn't work). I'm pretty sure they are the main cause of the lag.
You can kill it with this command (you may need to run multiple times if there's more than one, or just increase the limit parameter):
/minecraft:kill @e[type=ender_dragon, limit=1, sort=nearest]

You said you were using Paper/Spigot, so the minecraft: namespace part of the command to use the Minecraft one, because the one implemented in Paper doesn't accept entity targets (only players) and putting anything but another player (or *) will instead kill the player that ran it.
Also keep in mind that it may get very loud.

Have you tried /kill @entities? I am positive that it works on xbox minecraft
I am not sure though if it works on any platform other then what I play on. The only thing is I no clue if bedrock is the version I am playing on or not.

/kill @entities is not a real command
